# Abrir páginas secundárias em um espaço determinado AspNet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tenho uma página onde uso o `@renderBody` para abrir minhas páginas principais, porém surgiu a necessidade de obter um submenu e preciso que as páginas seguintes sejam abertas em um espaço determinado, mas quando disparo o *asp-controller asp-action* ele abre no local da `@renderBody`, como posso fazer para criar um tipo de `@renderBody2` no caso um `renderPage` ou `renderSection` mas que sejam abertos através de um clique de link?

Comment: Para resolver o caso temporariamente eu setei o layout novamente em cada página, o problema que tudo será carregado novamente a cada requisição.

Comment: O renderBody, renderSection são renderizados pelo servidor (server-side), e o que você está querendo é no client-side, talvez você tenha que resolver isso com JS, fazer com que o conteúdo do link seja carregado via AJAX em um determinado espaço da página (pelo id do elemento por exemplo). Outra solução seria identificar que essas ações são para serem abertas em um lugar alternativo, então na sua Layout você identificaria isso e ao trocaria o lugar do RenderBody (não sei se dá erro ter mais de um RenderBody na página, ou se pode usar um RenderBody condicional, só testando)